# Is "margin final" an ATC instruction in USA?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, phraseology

I was south-east of the airport and the active runway was 24. The ATC said, "Make straight in and remain south." And then he said, "Margin final, cleared [to] land."

What is margin final? I'm an international student so I may have misheard. I thought it's for joining final so I said, "Join final, cleared to land." The controller did not say anything after.

If it wasn't "margin final," what could it have been?

Comment: The literal answer to your question is no: the word "margin" isn't used that way in either the ATC orders or the PC/G. But if you want to know what the controller actually said, can you tell us which airport it was, the day and time you were there and your tail number? Someone may be able to find it on liveatc.net.

Comment: What about 'merge on the final'?